# Создание модуля maven в проекте gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Есть проект c тестами, в котором используется Gradle (условно - projectGradle). Требовалось создать в этом проекте модуль, но Maven (условно - projectMaven). Зависимый проект использует классы из основного, если подключать зависимость в настройках проекта (в идее) - то классы видимы и их можно использовать. Если же попробовать собрать этот зависимый модуль, то получаем ошибки, что классы из основного проекта не существуют. Что и где нужно прописать, чтобы не только идея, но и компилятор видел и собирал эти классы в зависимый проект?

Что было сделано:
В settings.gradle (находится в projectGradle) прописана строчка import 'projectMaven'
В pom.xml (в projectMaven) были попытки прописать теги parent и dependency, содержащие данные о projectGradle, после чего строчки просто загорались красным с сообщением "Dependency '....:projectGradle:1.1-SNAPSHOT' not found". Из чего могу сделать вывод, что он пытается искать такую библиотеку в Maven-репе.
Следуя инструкции [тут](https://andresalmiray.com/multi-module-project-builds-with-maven-and-gradle/), я создавала pom.xml в projectGradle, прописывала туда тег module projectMaven. Так как основной проект - тесты, и там есть "подмодули" main и test, я даже пыталась в модуле main создать pom.xml (ведь зависимость именно от main мне нужна).

Ничего из того, что я нашла/знала/предполагала не сработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы добавить зависимость на maven-проект для вашего gradle-проекта, можно воспользоваться возможностью публикации артефактов в локальный maven-репозиторий.

1. Создаем проект на maven, указываем в нем координаты артефакта (группа артефакта, имя и версия), [например](https://github.com/sirekanian/q1504582/blob/master/mavenProject/pom.xml):

   ```xml
   <groupId>org.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>projectMaven</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   ```
2. Выполняем установку артефакта в локальный maven-репозиторий. Для этого в терминале выполните команду `mvn install`. Если пользуетесь IDE, то найдите эту функцию в вашей IDE.
3. Во втором проекте, который на gradle, указываем репозиторий `mavenLocal` и [прописываем](https://github.com/sirekanian/q1504582/blob/master/gradleProject/build.gradle) зависимость на maven-артефакт:

   ```
   repositories {
       ...
       mavenLocal()
   }

   dependencies {
       ...
       implementation('org.example:projectMaven:1.0')
   }
   ```

Теперь, после пересборки gradle-проекта, вам будут доступны классы из maven-проекта.

Если остались вопросы, то ознакомтесь с [демо-проектом](https://github.com/sirekanian/q1504582).

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно наоборот, использовать проект с градлом в проекте с мавеном. То есть паковать я буду градл. Нашла таску publishToMavenLocal, возможно, это то, что мне нужно, но при запуске получаю ошибку > Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): 'C:\Kate\������\autotests\build\tmp\javadoc\javadoc.options' . Ищу пока пути решения

Comment: Да, такой вариант сработал, спасибо!

Comment: Если, наоборот, нужно подключить gradle-проект в maven-проект, то используйте официальный плагин [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html), посмотреть можно в [демо-проекте 2](https://github.com/sirekanian/q1504582-2).